# how to select multiple columns without anonymously return the result in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

how to select multiple columns without anonymously return the result in linq?

For Example

```
context.users.Where(user=> user.id ==10).Select(user => new{user.id, user.email}).FirstOrDefault();
```

but in that case I returned an anonymous object, so how can I return object of type user with the specified columns.

Comment: Are you always going to select one object? i.e. select by ID?

Answer (score 2):

Is the type `User` the same type as the members of `context.users`?

If so you can't choose the columns and you just do this:

```
context.users.Where(user => user.id == 10).FirstOrDefault();
```

However, if it is a different `User` type then you must do this:

```
context
    .users
    .Where(user => user.id == 10)
    .Select(user => new User { Id = user.id, Email = user.email })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or possibly this:

```
context
    .users
    .Where(user => user.id == 10)
    .Select(user => new { user.id, user.email })
    .Take(1)
    .ToArray()
    .Select(user => new User { Id = user.id, Email = user.email })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Get instance from user class then fill it with specified columns.

```
   context.users.Where(user=> user.id ==10).Select(user => new user{id=user.id,email= user.email}).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If the `user` class that your are new-ing up in the select method is the same user class used in the entity framework model, then this will throw a NotSupportedException exception

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var anonymous_object = context.users.Where(user=> user.id ==10).Select(user => new{user.id, user.email}).FirstOrDefault();

User user_object = null;

if(anonymous_object != null)
{
    user_object = new User()
    {
        id = anonymous_object.id,
        email = anonymous_object.email
    };
}
```